# Counting the number of iterations of a string in a dictionary with lists nested within

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm very new to python and playing with coding a simple game, and I'm just trying to find a way to count the number of iterations of a single word within a dictionary that contains other lists/dictionaries as well.

I've found lots of articles that come really -close- to explaining it (e.g. getting keys but not values), but I can't find quite what I'm looking for.  I'm also dumb, so there's that.

I've also come across people who have explained this with a function that exists in Python 3 but nothing yet works for me in Python 2.

I'd like to count the number of times the word "mammal" appears in the largest dictionary (named grandbestiary).

```
"""Bestiaries"""

levelonebestiary = {}
levelonebestiary["Babychick"] = [1, 10, "bird"]
levelonebestiary["Squirrel"] = [2, 15, "mammal"]
levelonebestiary["Washcloth"] = [0, 1, "cloth"]


leveltwobestiary = {}
leveltwobestiary["Large Frog"] = [3, 20, "amphibian"]
leveltwobestiary["Raccoon"] = [5, 15, "mammal"]
leveltwobestiary["Pigeon"] = [4, 20, "bird"]

nightmarebestiary = {}
nightmarebestiary["pumanoceros"] = [25, 500]

grandbestiary = [levelonebestiary, leveltwobestiary, nightmarebestiary]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `grandbestiary`  is a `list` not  a `dict`.

Comment: Yes, you're right--excuse me.  The trouble is, I'm still not able to get the values out of it.  Can you help?

Comment: There -are- dictionaries embedded in that list, and lists embedded within those dictionaries.  I'm sure you see the struggle--it's not a uniform type, and all that's returned to me is what's in the base list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: This code works perfectly as well, Tess--thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to achieve the count. Basically the same thing, but the second expressed as a comprehension. `iteritems` makes this python 2 code, but change it to `items` when you know you will be working with python 3 only.

Iterate the lists and then each contained dict. Then you can check the values in each dict entry to see if they contain the string "mammal". You may wish to further restrict it to check that only the 3rd element of the lists is equal to "mammal".

```
count = 0
for b in grandbestiary:
    for _, v in b.iteritems():
        if "mammal" in v:
            count += 1

count2 = sum("mammal" in v for b in grandbestiary for _, v in b.iteritems())
```

The variables `count` and `count2` hold the values. This assumes "mammal" only appears within the dictionary values list and not in the dictionary keys.

Or avoid using `iteritems` altogether, as we don't really care about the keys and you have a py2/3 solution.

```
count3 = sum("mammal" in v for b in grandbestiary for v in b.values())
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation--I have a sense of how to do this, going forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
levelonebestiary = {}
levelonebestiary["Babychick"] = [1, 10, "bird"]
levelonebestiary["Squirrel"] = [2, 15, "mammal"]
levelonebestiary["Washcloth"] = [0, 1, "cloth"]


leveltwobestiary = {}
leveltwobestiary["Large Frog"] = [3, 20, "amphibian"]
leveltwobestiary["Raccoon"] = [5, 15, "mammal"]
leveltwobestiary["Pigeon"] = [4, 20, "bird"]

nightmarebestiary = {}
nightmarebestiary["pumanoceros"] = [25, 500]

grandbestiary = [levelonebestiary, leveltwobestiary, nightmarebestiary]

mammal_count = 0
# iterate through all bestiaries in your list
for bestiary in grandbestiary:
    # iterate through all animals in your bestiary
    for animal in bestiary:
        # get the list (value) attached to each aniaml (key)
        animal_description = bestiary[animal]
        # check if "mammal" is in our array (value)
        if "mammal" in animal_description:
            mammal_count += 1

print (mammal_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick!

```
numOfMamals = 0
# Iterate over each bestiary
for bestiary in grandbestiary:
    # Snag each key string in the bestiary
    for key in bestiary:
        # Look at every item in the bestiary
        for item in bestiary[key]:
            if item == "mammal":
                numOfMamals = numOfMamals + 1

print numOfMamals
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the short syntax for this:

```
sum(1 for bestiary in grandbestiary if any("mammal" in l for l in bestiary.values()))
```